# I want the dropdown menu items to be within the vertical bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what I've been doing... I tried several things I found online such as making a button containing a list but it's not working s can anyone please help me

```css
.vertical-menu {
    display: block;
    /*padding-top: 150px;*/
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 200px; /* Set a width if you like */
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee !important; /* Grey background color */
  color: black !important; /* Black text color */
  display: block !important; /* Make the links appear below each other */
  padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline from links */
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc !important; /* Dark grey background on mouse-over */
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50 !important; /* Add a green color to the "active/current" link */
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-menu">
              <a href="#" class="">Home</a>
              <div class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" >Page 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              <a href="#">Link 4</a>
              <a href="#">Link 5</a>
              <a href="#">Link 6</a>
              <a href="#">Link 7</a>
```

it's not the same output but my point is that the dropdown menu items aren't within the vertical menu... I don't know if you guys understand me but I hope I you are.

Edit:

I want to make something like this[image]

Comment: do you mean you want all the links to show with no indentation for the sub-links? (or do you just want to get rid of the padding/bullets?).  By the way, not everything is important, you need to get rid of those if you want your code to work.. they'll override one another.

Comment: @RachelGallen could you please see the edit

Comment: so you don't want a sub-menu at all then?

Comment: no I need it... I need a menu which contains title and for example gender and each one of these will have it's options

Comment: so you wanna get rid of the bullets and padding then? Yes?

Comment: yes, the unnecessary things was just a try but I keep failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example has the sub-menu indented, achieved by the denoted extra css.  Please comment if you desire a different kind of appearance (boxes? custom bullets? ) I also removed the multiple !important s that were dotted around your css.

Hope this helps

```css
.vertical-menu {
  display: block;
  /*padding-top: 150px;*/
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  /* Set a width if you like */
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50%;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  /* Grey background color */
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*extra css*/

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 12px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.dropdown ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 12px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}


.vertical-menu .dropdown ul a {
  padding: 6px;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}


/* end extra*/

.vertical-menu a:active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Add a green color to the "active/current" link */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" class="">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  <a href="#">Link 7</a>
</div>
```

Comment: (I didn't do the toggle, i'm just wanting to know the layout is what you want; please comment)

Comment: well yes but not exactly. I want the page 1-1, page 1-2, page 1-3 to push the rest to the button

Comment: @Maha hi ( i went offline for a bit). Ok the easiest thing to do would be to incorporate the ul within the a probably then, because as-is the ul is not a child of the a (or you could do a make a top-level ul and then a child ul instead of having an a for the toggle)

Comment: @Maha run the snippet now? (you can adjust the padding)

Answer (score 0):

this answer is from W3.  Use the select tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The select element</h1>

<p>The select element is used to create a drop-down list:</p>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```